# MySQL Cast NULL to integer 0

Tags: mysql, integer, casting

How can I cast something that returns NULL to 0?

If this is my query: `select col from table;` would this be the right way to do it: `select cast(col as unsigned integer) from table;`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You'd probably want to use the [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(col, 0) FROM `table`;
```

`COALESCE()` returns the first non-`NULL` value in the list, or `NULL` if there are no non-`NULL` values.

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (id int, col int);

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2, NULL);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3, 300);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (4, NULL);
```

Result:

```
+------------------+
| COALESCE(col, 0) |
+------------------+
|              100 |
|                0 |
|              300 |
|                0 |
+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
SELECT IFNULL(col, 0) FROM `table`;
```

`IFNULL(expr1, expr2)` returns the first expression if it's not null, else returns the second expression.

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (id int, col int);

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2, NULL);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3, 300);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (4, NULL);
```

Result:

```
+----------------+
| IFNULL(col, 0) |
+----------------+
|            100 |
|              0 |
|            300 |
|              0 |
+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```